# yadcf bootstrap datetimepicker is not displaying when ScrollX is set to true

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yadcf

I'm trying to use yadcf plugin using bootstrap datetimepicker for filtering dates in my datatable.

[image]

The date picker is only visible when ScrollX is set to false. when set to true, the horizontal scrollbar appears then date picker is hidden behind the data rows.

[image]

i tried to set position:relative in .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget class. it is visible after setting it but textbox height is changing and date picker alignment issues occurring as below.

[image]

Any suggestions or pointers to resolve these issues?

Comment: does it work well with jquery datepicker?

Comment: I didn't try with jquery date picker as I use bootstrap CSS for my data table and would like to use bootstrap datetimepicker.

Comment: I will try to finish the integration of another bootstrap date-picker, hope it will resolve it https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/435 stay tuned

Comment: try the latest [yadcf beta](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/fa56e7d2c399cb4b12e2459df25063b1e7850e23/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) and use the following date picker plugin https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel for the updated plugin. The datepicker is showing now when ScrollX set to true.  
I modified yadcf plugin(Line:1773) from $("#" + dateId).datepicker({}); to $("#" + dateId).datepicker(datepickerObj); as i need to set datepicker options and it worked after this change.

Comment: I have observed the following 
1) Previously, on selection of date on date picker the search filter triggers and shows the matches(rows) but looks like now it is not happening.
2) Date pickers are shown multiple. In other words, on focus out the current date picker is still shown.
   Could you please let me know if i missed anything or provide some pointers on how to resolve these?

Comment: More clarification on second point - 
2) Date picker is still shown on click of another input filed. In other words, without the selection of date on first date picker, i clicked on another input field the first date picker is still shown along with second date picker.

Comment: fixed some in 0.9.3.beta.7 , please open an issue on github + provide a test page for remaining issues

Comment: I have created an issue for #1 point
https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/441

Comment: I have created an issue #2 point https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/442

Comment: Created Test page for 441 and 442 issues
http://jsfiddle.net/umamaheswarcs/UvjnT/2975/

Comment: Hi Daniel, it took me sometime for test page creation as i'm new to jsfiddle. sorry for the delay.

Comment: Hi, you test page were ok, I fixed/closed on of your issues and only one left to be fixed "Date picker is still shown on click of another input filed" if something is not clear/works for you let me know

Answer (score 0):

Use the yadcf 0.9.3.beta.7 version with a similar setup

```
$('#example').dataTable().yadcf([{
    column_number: 4, 
    filter_type: "range_date", 
    datepicker_type: 'bootstrap-datepicker', 
    date_format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
}]);
```

and add the [uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) plugin to your web app

Comment: In case of range_date the filter is having two textboxes asking for start and end date to filter. is it not possible with filter_type:date? it works with filter_type:"range_date".

Comment: Will check... You can debug to pinpoint the issue to speed up the fix

Comment: no need in moment usage anymore for this date picker